# Testing for Topology

Tags: general-topology

Is $\tau=\lbrace G: G\subset \mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}\subset G\rbrace$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

I think this is not. If we choose $G_n=\left\lbrace 1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n!}\right\rbrace$, then $\bigcup\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}G_n=\left\lbrace 1+\dfrac{1}{1!},\ldots,e\right\rbrace$. Is it correct?

Comment: $G_n$ is a singleton here? Why is $e$ in the union?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct. The limit you write does not contain $e$, although $e$ is in the "closure" of it (I say closure but with the usual topology, NOT $\tau$)! Be careful with your intuition!

$\tau$ is a topology. First, all $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\tau$, since it contains $\mathbb{Q}$. Secondly, if two sets are either in $\mathbb{Q}$ or contain $\mathbb{Q}$, then so do their intersection. The same with an arbitrary union.

Comment: What properties does the space have? for sure it is $T_0$ and it is seperable (take $\mathbb{Q}$, as every open set does have rational points, the intersection with every non empty open set is non empty hense $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense). But we aren't $T_1$

Comment: Well, take $x$ to be rational and $y$ to be irrational, and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $y$. Since $y$ is irrational, $U$ cannot be contained in $\mathbb{Q}$, and so $U$ must contain $\mathbb{Q}$ and hence $x$. This shows that the closure of any irrational point $y$ is $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{y\}$. On the other hand, any rational point is open, and so the space is at least $T_0$. By the example I just said, it can't be $T_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not work.  In order for $e$ to be in $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ there must be an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $e \in G_n$, but no such $n$ exists.